# Google Chrome is converting text urls to "<a href=" links

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have urls that I want to be displayed as text e.g.

http://www.google.com that I don't want to be clickable.

I noticed that Google Chrome is automatically converting text http://www.google.com to clickable links e.g. `<a href="http://www.google.com"> http://www.google.com</a>`.

I don't want these text to be clickable. I jsut want them to be displayed as text only.

Comment: it'll never happen if you're actually writing `http://google.com` inside html file directly

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. I just tested it on my site in google chrome. It's not clickable.

```
    <a>http://www.google.com</a>
```